# Meaning of 掛かってるも掛かった

Tags: meaning

I'm not quite sure how to understand the bolded part in the below. What is the も in the sentence doing?　I get that the joke is a play on words but I'm not sure what is being said.

「飯食ってる最中に漫才聞かされんのかよ！　噴飯ものだぜ！」

「ご飯とご飯が、掛かってますね！」

「噴飯だから、**掛かってるも掛かった**な！」

Answer (score 4, accepted):

噴飯もの is a phrase used when one thinks something is absurd. It literally means something that makes one spit out food (laughing). The second person sees wordplay between ご飯 and 噴飯 and points that out using the verb 掛かる. The first person, in turn, sees wordplay in the use of that verb because when you spit out food, it will splash over things, and the same verb 掛かる is used to describe that.

It should be read as 「掛かってる」も掛かったな with quotation marks. The particle も here simply means “also” or “too”.

Comment: If I may ask, how did you make that inference with 「ご飯とご飯」(how he's pointing out wordplay between ご飯 and 噴飯) ? Also, what definition does 掛かった fall under here, and why did they use the simple past tense instead of present progressive like written in the line before?

Comment: The verb 掛かる is used to mean one word kind of “overlaps” with another in meaning, sound, etc. with a funny or interesting result. If you know this meaning, there is no other interpretation for ご飯とご飯. One of them must be the food behind the etymology of 噴飯. Regarding the past tense, I supposed it was because 掛かってる “overlapping” with 噴飯 was an unexpected discovery. The second line, on the other hand, was a simple observation. 掛かってるな or 掛かってたな in the third line would also sound perfectly natural.

Comment: Thank you. I just thought that they would've written 噴飯とご飯 to indicate said wordplay, since repeating ご飯 twice seems odd to me. I'm probably just missing something here, though.

Comment: I understand you. I myself would have probably said 飯（めし）と噴飯, using the exact words the first person used.